# Why does the Groovy JSONBuilder escape slashes in URLs?

Tags: json, groovy

I am writing a Groovy script that needs to POST JSON to a URL. I have noticed a problem were all elements in my JSON that contains a '/' are changed to '\/' by the JSON Builder. Is there a way to stop this?

This is using Groovy 1.8. Here is a simple example and its output:

```
def json = new JsonBuilder()
    json.reply {
    result 'http://google.ie/testing'
}

println json.toString()

Output -> {"reply":{"result":"http:\/\/google.ie\/testing"}}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you must be referring to a class from grails. There doesn't seem to be any `JsonBuilder` provided by groovy http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/index.html

Comment: @Don it is [included in 1.8](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)

Comment: @tim_yates - how come I don't see it listed in the 1.8 docs (linked above)?

Comment: @Don no idea... it's in the gapi docs http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/index.html ... I'm confused now as to which docs are supposed to be which...  The api docs are missing some classes though... I guess this needs putting in the JIRA, or mentioning on the user list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a look, and `groovy.json.JsonOuput.toJson(string)` encodes forward slash as `'\\/'`.

You can use `toPrettyString` and it doesn't do it however:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

json.reply {
  result 'http://google.ie/testing'
}

assert json.toPrettyString() == '''{
    "reply": {
        "result": "http://google.ie/testing"
    }
}'''
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the Groovy JSONBuilder escape slashes in URLs?

An excerpt of the interesting points made in http://groups.google.com/group/opensocial-and-gadgets-spec/browse_thread/thread/1642ec0bed9b95ba/21956eed23f04e13?pli=1 on this topic:

- Arne Roomann-Kurrik: Per the JSON spec, escaping '/' is optional.
- Mike Samuel: The solidus is among the set of characters that MAY be escaped so that it is safe to embed the JSON substring `</script>` in HTML as `<\/script>`.  (Half of this quote is by [Andrea Ercolino](http://noteslog.com/post/the-solidus-issue/).)
- Kevin Brown: This is primarily due to buggy javascript parsers that treat // as a comment
  when it's in a string.