# Android sending base64 string json error on encoding

Tags: android, json, base64

I think I'm getting a weird encoding error when I encode an image to base 64 and try to send it through a JSON.

I'm encoding the photo that starts as a Bitmap like this:

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
            encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and the I send the "encoded" String on the json

```
            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

            postDataParams.put(ArchivoTexto, encoded);
```

now the problem that I see is that when I send the JSON the encoded string that the console says its sending something that looks like this:

```
\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wB
```

but if I copy to the clipboard the "encoded" String it looks like this:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wB
```

the backslashes disappear, and if I use a website to decode the string that comes from the clipboard it successfully decodes the image, but when I send the string to a server through the JSON it just looks broken, so I suspect that the backslashes are making it break.

My question is should I look for a way to remove the backslashes before sending the string on a JSON or is the server's fault for not being able to interpret the string correctly?

Comment: how does your back end receives the data ? "Code please"

Comment: This may help you: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565224/5343320)

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan I am not handling the server backend, thats why I need to know if its a problem I am causing or the server is the problem

Comment: @huk hey thanks, but please confirm to me what I could understand, the json parser on the server end should identify that there are escape characters on the string and remove them, and I shouldn't remove them before sending the string.

Comment: @gtovar a possible issue is that your Base64 is different that their Base64 implementation ... so you'll have to look at their API and check which Base64 are they using and track that problem down to find what is going on ... I ran to the same problem once between android and PHP server, where I used different Base64 than the PHP server which caused me a similar issue

Comment: @gtovar or it might be what 'huk' said :) ... who knows ... we don't have codes or logs ... we can only assume for you

Answer (score 0):

for upload image i do this :

```
VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, G.SET_AVATAR_URL, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

  }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
  }
}) {
  @Override
  protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
    Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("avatar", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), img_user.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));
    return params;
  }
};

VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```

}

this is AppHelper class :

```
    public class AppHelper {

  /**
   * Turn drawable resource into byte array.
   *
   * @param context parent context
   * @param id      drawable resource id
   * @return byte array
   */
  public static byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Context context, int id) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
  }

  /**
   * Turn drawable into byte array.
   *
   * @param drawable data
   * @return byte array
   */
  public static byte[] getFileDataFromDrawable(Context context, Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
  }
}
```

and this is link for VolleyMultipartRequest : [Link github](https://github.com/anggadarkprince/infogue-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sketchproject/infogue/modules/VolleyMultipartRequest.java)